# Selenium (python) testing a React-js frontend leads to stale error message when trying to input text into input field

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium

I have a vague idea what my issue is but no idea how to overcome it in Selenium.  The React-js frontend updates the DOM on every character of text input into the input field, so Selenium sees that the DOM has changed so my variable reference no longer points at the correct DOM element, and so is stale, even though on reload of the DOM, the element does actually still exist and so I get the following:

```
Message: The element reference of <input class="input-1" name="firstname" type=""> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

My example lines in my test would be like this:

```
def test_fill_in_name_and_submit_with_enter(self):
    firstname_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name('firstname')
    firstname_input.send_keys('Adam')
    firstname_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The first character gets entered and then the test fails with the preceding message.  There are some answers in Stackoverflow but they make no sense to me, the code seems to convoluted and specific to the use case whereas the above is very generic and simple, so maybe we can get a simple answer for what must be becoming a very common issue these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, don't do this.  This was a problem with my JS code which was causing the issue which I replicated by trying it out myself after rebuilding my code.  If I tried typing it would deselect the input box because of some weird arrow function stuff that I was doing.  I reverted to just static inputs and this was fine afterwards and testing with send_keys works as expected.

---

Okay, so in the end I've done this in what looks like a horrible and hacky way but this may just be because my React-js app is set up with an onChange which sets the state value equal to the input field data:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def enter_text_into_input_fields(browser, text, field_name):
    for l in text:
        browser.find_element(By.NAME, field_name).send_keys(l)

class SomeBasicTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.get(f'{self.live_server_url}/')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_fill_in_name_and_submit_with_enter(self):
        enter_text_into_input_fields(self.browser, 'Adam', 'firstname')
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('firstname').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        app_title = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('html body div#app.app h1').text
        self.assertIn('This is our app title', app_title)
```